# Service Fabric Corrupt: SfDevCluster not created

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have installed Service Fabric, and although the cluster explorer has installed, I have noticed that the standard SFDevCluster folder has not been created

The error message in the local cluster manager is useless - error occurred resetting cluster.

I then delved into the PowerShell side and got the message below.

I am out of ideas and getting pretty frustrated!  This has installed loads of other times on other machines without any issues at all.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times.

I have added Service Fabric to Visual Studio.

```
    PS C:\program files\microsoft sdks\service fabric\clustersetup> .\DevClusterSetup.ps1
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Refresh'.
Get-Module : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Refresh'.
At C:\program files\microsoft sdks\service fabric\clustersetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1:54 char:35
+ Get-Module -ListAvailable -Refresh <<<<  --quiet *>$null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Module], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetModuleCommand

PS C:\program files\microsoft sdks\service fabric\clustersetup>
```

I have even tried to copy my Service Fabric files over to the machine and that doesn't work either.

Has anyone ever had anything like this?  Please note that these issues are occurring outside Visual Studio (2017).

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally have these kind of problems when I upgrade my local cluster runtime and SDK.

This specific error I've not faced yet, but the rule of thumb I always follow when the update fails (that is pretty often) is:

- Remove Local Cluster via *SF Cluster Manager* App
- Uninstall the old SDK and Runtime version
- **Restart the computer**
- Install the new versions
- **Restart the computer**
- Setup the cluster via *SF Cluster Manager* if not already set as part of the setup

I could notice that most issues I had with SF installations was related to the old resources not being totally wiped out from the machine, when installing new ones, something left behind was affecting the new installation, after following these steps, I've  never had issues again.

Regarding your error message, issue might be because you are running these scripts directly, and they are  intended to be run from *SF Cluster Manager* App. Also, I would not be surprised if any modules are still loaded when these PS scripts run.